# Python: Export huge number as string from Excel File

Tags: python, excel, pandas

trying to get a column from excel file, this column has values like= 819195861645728953,213234621044503745. When I get the dataframe device column change all the values as: 8.19195861645729e+17, 2.132346210445037e+17 even if I changed to str or put this:

```
File['device'] = File.apply(lambda x: "'" + str(x.device) , axis = 1)
```

The value always showed in wrong format

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

NewFilePath =r'C:\Users\318459\Downloads\\'#AQUI CAMBIO  
NewFile='AAACB Main 5.7.2021.xlsx' #AQUI CAMBIO
NewFilePath =NewFilePath.replace('\\', '/')
File= pd.read_excel(f'{NewFilePath}{NewFile}', sheet_name="Sheet1")

File['device']=File['device'].values.astype(str)
File=File[['device']]
```

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop pandas from inferring the dtype when it imports the data, otherwise it's too late. Do this by specifying the `dtype` upon import.

```
File = pd.read_excel(f'{NewFilePath}{NewFile}', sheet_name='Sheet1', 
                     dtype={'device': 'str'})
```